# DON'T SEND DUPLICATE EMAIL (SAS)

Tags: email, sas

I have the following code that is checking when a table was last modified and if that date equals today will then send out a notification email. I have this code x3 for 3 different tables I am monitoring.

```
filename myemail EMAIL
to="john.doe@test.com"
cc=""
from="me.myself@test.com"
;

data _null_;
file myemail;
if _n_=1 and eof then put '!EM_ABBORT!';
set test end=eof;
where (memname = 'class' and datepart(modate) = date());
    put "Hello";
    put" ";
    put"This is a test email";
    put" ";
    put memname= ;
    put modate= ;
    put" ";
    put"Many thanks";
run;
```

The problem i have is that once the criteria is met and an email has been sent (person has been notified) i don't want the same email sent again next time the code runs as they have already been notified about that specific table. The code is scheduled (Windows Scheduler) to run every hour.

I believe I need to record what email was sent somewhere. Someone suggested it could be done with boolean or date_email_sent field in my dataset(s).

Can anyone provide me an example code of how the best way to achieve this???

Many thanks

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

here is some food for thought.

```
/*tab1 is the table we want to monitor for a change*/
data tab1;
col1='a';
run;

/*initial load of log_table - this table contains the last modified date of the table(s) we monitor*/
proc contents noprint data=tab1 out=columns(keep=libname memname modate);quit;
proc sql;
create table log_table as 
select distinct *
from columns
;quit;

/*wait a second*/
%let rc = %sysfunc(sleep(1));

/*now we update tab1*/
proc sql;
insert into tab1 values ('b')
;quit;

/*check when tab1 was last modified*/
proc contents noprint data=tab1 out=columns(keep=libname memname modate);quit;
proc sql;
create table last_modate as 
select distinct 
     libname
    ,memname 
    ,modate as new_modate
from columns
;quit;

/*and compare the current modate with modate from the last run*/
data log_table(drop=new_modate);
merge log_table (in=a)
      last_modate (in=b);
by libname memname;
if modate ne new_modate then do;
    /*check other conditions, send an email, ...*/
    modate = new_modate;
end;
run;
```

For monitoring multiple tables, just keep the log_table sorted so it can be used in merge.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am trying to get my head around your code (should have mentioned that i'm a newbie to SAS) i'm trying to figure out where and how to incorporate my existing code into yours??? Could you provide an example please???

Comment: Is there someone who can help you with the coding? It's not a copy&paste kind of task. You will need to decide where to store the "log" table, you might want to add some checks (e.g. if the table exists), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Petr's idea is solid. I built on he's ideas and came up with following.

I suggest making permanent data, which stores who to send mail and who has been sent and what date:

```
data res_mails;
    input mail $;
    cards;
    'mail1' 
    'mail2' 
    'mail3'
;run;

data sent_mails;
    input date mail $;
    cards;  ;
ruN;
```

Next we select the select the ones who you can send mail. (==Who have not been sent today.) I leave the trigger condition to your hand. (Just add category variable to res_mails table. )

```
%macro select_and_update_recipiants;
    proc sql; /*the selection bit*/
        select distinct(mail) into: respList separated by ' ' 
        from res_mail
        where mail not in (
        select( select distinct(mail) from sent_mails 
            where date=date();
            )
        )
    quit;
    /*The update bit. Go through the mails that will be sent and add them to list that have been sent.*/
    data sent_mails;
        set sent_mail;
        %for i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&SYSPARM.,' '));
            date=date();
            mail=%scan(&repList.,&i,' ');
            output;
        %end;
%mend;

%sendMail_to_resplist;
```

Disclaimer: Not tested.